# PyYAML, safe_dump adding line breaks and indent to the YAML file

Tags: python-2.7, pyyaml

I want to receive following YAML file:

```
---
classes:
  - apache
  - ntp

apache::first: 1
apache::package_ensure: present
apache::port: 999
apache::second: 2
apache::service_ensure: running

ntp::bla: bla
ntp::package_ensure: present
ntp::servers: '-'
```

After parsing, I received such output:

```
---
apache::first: 1
apache::package_ensure: present
apache::port: 999
apache::second: 2
apache::service_ensure: running
classes:
- apache
- ntp
ntp::bla: bla
ntp::package_ensure: present
ntp::servers: '-'
```

[Here](https://dpinte.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/pyaml-dump-option/), I have found the properties that give possibility to style document. I tried to set line_break and indent, but it does not work.

```
 with open(config['REPOSITORY_PATH'] + '/' + file_name, 'w+') as file:
            yaml.safe_dump(data_map, file, indent=10, explicit_start=True, explicit_end=True, default_flow_style=False,
                           line_break=1)
        file.close()
```

Please, advice me simple approach to style the output.

Comment: You should not explicitly call `file.close()`, exiting the with statement closes the file for you (even if an exception occurs)

Answer (score 7):

You cannot do that in PyYAML. The `indent` option only affects mappings and not sequences. PyYAML also doesn't preserve order of mapping keys on round-tripping.

If you use [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) (dislaimer: I am the author of that package), then getting the exact same input as output is easy:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
---
classes:
  - apache   # keep the indentation
  - ntp

apache::first: 1
apache::package_ensure: present
apache::port: 999
apache::second: 2
apache::service_ensure: running

ntp::bla: bla
ntp::package_ensure: present
ntp::servers: '-'
"""

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
res = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, indent=4, block_seq_indent=2,
                            explicit_start=True)
assert res == yaml_str
```

please note that it also preserves the comment I added to the first sequence element.

---

You can build this from "scratch" but adding a newline is not something for which a call exists in `ruamel.yaml`:

```
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.tokens import CommentToken
from ruamel.yaml.error import Mark
from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap, CommentedSeq


data = CommentedMap()
data['classes'] = classes = CommentedSeq()
classes.append('apache')
classes.append('ntp')

data['apache::first'] = 1
data['apache::package_ensure'] = 'present'
data['apache::port'] = 999
data['apache::second'] = 2
data['apache::service_ensure'] = 'running'
data['ntp::bla'] = 'bla'
data['ntp::package_ensure'] = 'present'
data['ntp::servers'] = '-'


m = Mark(None, None, None, 0, None, None)
data['classes'].ca.items[1] = [CommentToken('\n\n', m, None), None, None, None]
#                        ^ 1 is the last item in the list
data.ca.items['apache::service_ensure'] = [None, None, CommentToken('\n\n', m, None), None]

res = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, indent=4, block_seq_indent=2,
                            explicit_start=True)
print(res, end='')
```

You will have to add the newline as comment (without '`#`') to the last element before the newline, i.e. the last list element and the `apache::service_ensure` mapping entry.

---

Apart from that you should ask yourself if you really want to use PyYAML which only supports (most of) YAML 1.1 from 2005 and not the latest revision YAML 1.2 from 2009.

The wordpress page you linked to doesn't seem very serious (it doesn't even have the package name, `PyYAML`, correct).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want. In my case, the input data is a dict generate from the request body  and looks like this : `{u'apache::package_ensure': u'present', u'apache::first': 1, u'ntp::bla': 'bla', u'apache::second': 2, 'classes': [u'apache', u'ntp'], u'ntp::package_ensure': u'present', u'ntp::servers': u'-', u'apache::service_ensure': u'running', u'apache::port': 999}`.  Is there way to gain desired format (as above) from that dict. Or I should additionally process it?

Comment: Everything but the empty lines is trivial. You just have to create a `CommentedMap` instance  (`from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap`) and assign the values to  keys in the order you want them and then dump that instance. I would have to look into the details for adding the empty lines, but it is generally more easy to load a rough correct YAML file and flesh it out. Do you always have the same keys with differing values? Or at least always 3 sections that need seperation with empty line?

Comment: The user is generating the yaml file from the UI, by selecting different keys and setting values.  Therefore, keys could be different, and number of section also can be different (less then three)

Comment: I updated the answer to do this from scratch, not very elegant, but doable.